# Without using GAC, best way to share DLL between multiple web applications IIS

Tags: c#, dll, web-applications, share

In a perfect world, I want to do the following..

On my base **website** in IIS, I want to have a bin folder that houses all DLLs that our company uses for all of its websites.  We have about 20 or so, as well as a bunch of default microsoft ones.   On each web **application** under this default website, I want to just want to include the DLLs needed specifically for that application (for instance, one site has a specific library we use to sync products that isn't used anywhere else).

The point of this is so that if we have a new "base" dll, changing out one file will affect all of our websites.

I want to be able to use msdeploy / parameterized web.config files with multiple deployments for dev / test / prod.  Its just important that msdeploy be used due to our extensive pre-existing deployment configurations in our Atlassian Bamboo deployment CI stuff.

I do not want to use the GAC to host the DLLs. They will change frequently as we push new versions out.

I have googled and have not found anyone that has some close to doing what I say. I'm toying around with attempting to modify  in the csproj file, but i'm pretty sure that won't do anything for a compiled source.

Comment: How about having a private nuget feed where you host your own packages and share those ?

Comment: We do this, however i don't want to have to build and redeploy all of the web applications... Just the base site if something changes for all of them.

Comment: Sounds like those dlls should be microservices.

Comment: Just what @Crowcoder said, without the microservices buzzword. You probably would need to write a shared HTTP/RPC/whatever API for those common functionalities...

Comment: hmm. well, we don't write the DLLs. They are 3rd party from a vendor, but i like the idea and will be giving it more thought.  This stuff is pretty complex, and that would be a major undertaking.  These are mature systems we are trying to streamline.

Comment: You can wrap a service around the dlls, you don't have to recreate the logic.

Comment: Is this feasable when the dll's contain thousands of functions?

Comment: @CarComp you mean you would like to "export" or "wrap" thousands of functions to an API? That sounds awkward to me... Couldn't those thousands just "put" together to use-cases?

Comment: Instead of writing a wrapper around your thousands functions, write a generator that will generate your wrapper. You will only have to write it once and run the generator each time there are changes.